# Do whales ever just hang out on the surface breathing?

Tags: ethology, mammals, marine-biology

You only ever hear of whales surfacing for a brief second to exhale/inhale before they dive back down. But do they ever just stay at surface level, laying there with their blow hole up in the air, continuously breathing for a while? One would think that might be a relaxing experience for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whales often hang out on the surface for a while, for a number of reasons. Sometimes it is for curiosity, sometimes to socialize with other whales, and sometimes simply to rest.  The particular sort behavior that you are describing sounds like [logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetacean_surfacing_behaviour#Logging), where the whale basically rests, often for an extended period of time, with its back slightly out of the water, looking sort of like a floating log.

Comment: Cool, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, I can attest to the fact that whales will hang out on the surface. Additionally, some species are more known among researchers/observers for this behavior. *Kogia* species (dwarf and pygmy sperm whales) are notorious for logging, for example. This [study](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/mms.12861) from Hawaii mentions that dwarf sperm whales spent a considerable amount of time in encounters either slow rolling at the surface or logging.